# Как хранить комментарии в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Как хранить комментарии в БД. Я так понимаю должно быть две таблицы.
Например: посты и комментарии и в таблице с постами, в каждой строке должно быть поле с перечисленными id комментов ?

Comment: Нет.  
ИД комментария (primary key, index)  
ИД поста к которому комментарий относится (index)  
ИД пользователя, который сделал комментарий (index если захотите показать все комментарии одного пользователя)  
Дата создания комментария (timestamp)  
Текст комментария.  
Другие поля по необходимости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Например: посты и комментарии и в таблице с постами, в каждой строке должно быть поле с перечисленными id комментов ?

Нужно две таблицы: 1) Посты. Ну там текст поста, кто создал и т. п. 2) Комменты. Среди прочего должно быть поле, где указано, к какому посту относится. Далее смотрите по своей архитектуре: будет ли это id поста (что логично) или что-то еще. Отображать все это обычным `SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE POST_ID = ID;`