# Индексы БД: зачем явно указывать их, если внешние ключи можно знать и неформально?

Tags: структуры-данных, mysql, проектирование, база-данных, индексы

Выдержка из первого же комментария тов. @ReinRaus к вопросу [Как хранить комментарии в БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207570/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4):

> ИД поста к которому комментарий относится (index)
>
> ИД пользователя, который сделал комментарий (index если захотите показать все комментарии одного пользователя)

Я вот не пойму, зачем для этих столбцов устанавливать индекс? Понятно, что в этих полях хранятся ссылки на другие строки (в этом случае — в другой таблице). Можно же и не указывать явно, что в этом столбце хранятся ссылки, а не просто какие-то данные. Так вот, зачем это? Для производительности (может, строки будут как-то кешироваться группами)? Или может, просто, для наглядности: мол, это не просто какие-то цифры, а именно внешние ключи?

Речь о MySQL.

Comment: Индекс по столбцу "ИД поста" нужен, чтобы быстрее искать все комментарии для конкретного поста.

Аналогично, индекс по "ИД пользователя" ускорит выборку всех постов одного пользователя.

Автоматически навешивать индексы бессмысленно, так как далеко не всегда внешний ключ является критерием выборки. А каждый индекс на таблице замедляет вставку/обновление/удаление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс нужен не для того, чтобы указать внешние ключи, а для повышения производительности при выборке по проиндексированным полям. Логично, что при выборке комментариев к посту вы будете использовать что-то вроде `select [поля] from comments where post_id = 123`, причём подобные запросы будут возникать достаточно часто. Тут и скажется индексирование - поиск значения 123 среди `post_id` всех записей будет происходить быстрее, ести поле `post_id` проиндексировано. Аналогичными причинами можно обосновать индексацию ID пользователя и ID комментария (хотя, придумать ситуацию, в которой нам будет нужно вытянуть один коммент я не смог).

Comment: Даже при непростых запросах (ну, к примеру `post_id BETWEEN 10 and 50` или при слиянии с другой таблицей `JOIN`-ом) индексация повлияет на производительность?

Answer (score 2):

Индексы существенно ускоряют поиск по данному полю если говорить коротко.

> Можно же и не указывать явно, что в
> этом столбце хранятся ссылки, а не
> просто какие-то данные.

а вот указывая что поле является ссылкой, а не просто мифической цифиркой вы обеспечиваете целостность данных в вашем хранилище. Ибо как минимум вам не удастся записать строку которая ссылается на не существующую запись, либо вы никогда не удалите запись на которую множество ссылок из других таблиц чем опять же обеспечите целостность данных.

Comment: упс, ответили пока писал )

Comment: То есть, если на данную строку ссылаются другие строки, то запрос `DELETE` по отношению к данной строке завершится неудачей? А за рамками MySQL (это общепринятое поведение или нет)?

Пошел пробовать..

Comment: Если задано поведение CASCADE или SET NULL, SET DEFAULT - удалится

Answer (score 0):

Для внешних ключей индекс по умолчанию не создается. В отличие от первичных